# An object component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm trying to render a form with a few different form-steps (details, payments, confirm...) from a UI library that has Form component ready, which iterates through those form-steps.

The issue is that each 'step' component looks more like an actual JS object:

```
export const DetailStep = (
    <div>Details screen with inputs, texts and images...</div> 
);
```

It doesn't have the `= () =>` so it's not an actual functional component, so I can't add hooks or functions into it.

That's the array of steps:

```
const stepPages = [
  DetailStep,
  PaymentStep,
  ConfirmStep
];
```

And that's the actual Form component that iterates through the array of steps:

```
<Form
  onSubmitClick={onStepSubmit}
  render={formRenderProps => {stepPages[step]} } 
/>
```

If I'll change any step to a functional component (`DetailStep = () => ...`), the step will be blank and won't be rendered.
How can I fix that / just add hooks to each 'step' component?

Comment: Can you set up a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or something similar with a simple example of what you are trying?

Comment: Which UI library? the API of the `<Form` component will matter

Comment: looks like KendoReact?

Comment: @FredStark Correct.

Comment: @jharris711  This is the original code, the steps are shown there, my example is the second one (the bottom one):       https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/form/multi-step-form/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX declarations are converted into `React.createElement` function calls, this does mean that the `stepPages` in your example are objects (just that they are react objects)

The magic that turns them into function components happens in the `render` prop of the form:

```
<Form
  onSubmitClick={onStepSubmit}
  render={formRenderProps => {stepPages[step]} } 
/>
```

You can see that it's passing a function in here, that returns the jsx objects. This is kinda the same as putting the jsx directly in the render function.

Although I notice that in your example, the jsx isn't being returned, so I would expect this example to not work correctly.

The longform equivalent would be something like this:

```
<Form
  onSubmitClick={onStepSubmit}
  render={formRenderProps => {
    if (step === 0) {
      return (
        <div>Details screen with inputs, texts and images...</div> 
      )
    } else if (step === 1) {
      return (
        <div>Details screen with inputs, texts and images...</div> 
      )
    } // etc
  }} 
/>
```

---

EDIT to answer question in comments

> You're right, so how can I add hooks into those object components?

If each of the form steps needs to use hooks and manage it's internal state, then I would make them functional components instead of JSX objects, then pick the right component from the `stepPages` map and render it like so:

```
export const DetailStep = (props) => {
  // hooks and stuff here
  return (
    <div>Details screen with inputs, texts and images...</div> 
  );
}
```

```
const StepComponent = stepPages[step];
return (
  <Form
    onSubmitClick={onStepSubmit}
    render={formRenderProps => <StepComponent {...formRenderProps} />} 
  />
);
```

Comment: You're right, so how can I add hooks into those object components?